# How to make a particular area of qml view transparent

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

There is a qml file like this:

```
Item {
    width: 800
    height: 600

    Image {
        id: background
        width: 800
        height: 600
        source: "qrc:/resorces/background.png"
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: transframe
        x: 500
        y: 200
        width: 200
        height: 100
    }

}
```

How to make the area of transframe transparent, then I can see the graphic under background.

Comment: It would be beneficial if you could add screenshots of what you are noticing. Perhaps you could set color:"transparent" property for the transframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [OpacityMask](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtgraphicaleffects-opacitymask.html) is what you are looking for.

Example:

```
    Rectangle {
        width: 800; height: 600
        color: 'red'

        Image {
            id: background
            width: 800; height: 600
            source: "qrc:/resorces/background.png"
            visible: false
        }
        Item {
            id: transframe
            width: 800; height: 600
            visible: false
            Rectangle {
                x: 500; y: 200; width: 200; height: 100
            }
        }
        OpacityMask { // don't forget to import QtGraphicalEffects
            anchors.fill: background
            source: background
            maskSource: transframe
            invert: true
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer, the OpacityMask is what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Andrii I'm using Qt 5.6, but the property of invert is introduced in Qt 5.7. I think it maybe useful to make maskSource as the area except transframe in Qt 5.6.   Is there any other way?

Comment: @CN.Hu The simplest way, I believe, is to replace the hole `Rectangle` within `transframe` with four `Rectangle`'s around the hole. Or draw a mask  image with your favourite drawing app and load it to `Image`.

Comment: @Andrii The simplest way is same as what I think, thank you very much!~

Answer (score 0):

```
Item { 
    width: 800 
    height: 600
    Image {
        id: background
        width: 800
        height: 600
        source: "qrc:/resorces/background.png"
    }
    Rectangle {
        id: transframe
        x: 500
        y: 200
        width: 200
        height: 100
        color:"transparent"
    }
}
```

Comment: transframe can be transparent, but the area of transframe in background still non-transparent. I still can't see the graphic under background.